# Yank list of lines into a register in vimscript

Tags: vimscript, cut-copy-paste, register

I am writing a function and I wish to yank a range of lines into a register.
The line that I cannot fix is the following:

```
let @" = getline(l:line_in,l:line_out)
```

where `l:line_in` and `l:line` out are line numbers.
The error that I get is `E730: Using a List as a String`.
In my understanding, the problem relies in `getline(a,b)` that returns a list with all the lines between line number `a` and line number `b`, but then how shall I convert it to fit into a register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `join()` function to join an array to a string:

```
let @" = getline(l:line_in, l:line_out)->join("\n")
```

In this case, you probably want to join them by newlines as text; alternatively, you can use the `string()` function to get the representation as an array literal (`[…]`):

```
let @" = getline(l:line_in, l:line_out)->string()
```

This can be useful for debugging things and such. `printf()` is also useful for this.

---

Example:

```
:echo getline(1, 3)->join("\n")
/* vi:set ts=8 sts=4 sw=4 noet:
 *
 * VIM - Vi IMproved    by Bram Moolenaar

:echo getline(1, 3)->string()
['/* vi:set ts=8 sts=4 sw=4 noet:', ' *', ' * VIM - Vi IMproved by Bram Moolenaar']
```

Comment: Many thanks! `join` is what I needed!

Comment: Possibly `:help setreg()` is better